# Can I use PDFBox to set a document to modify=false without requiring a password

Tags: pdfbox

I want to create a PDF with can modify equal to false and readonly = true without needing a password, i.e. anyone can read the document and no one can modify it. It seems the policy object forces a password and I see no method to use the accesspermission object without a policy object. Below is the code I tried.

```
        PDDocument documentToProtect= PDDocument.load(document);
        AccessPermission ap = new AccessPermission();
        ap.setCanModify(false);
        ap.setReadOnly();
        StandardProtectionPolicy policy = new StandardProtectionPolicy(null,null, ap);
        documentToProtect.protect(policy);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
StandardProtectionPolicy policy = new StandardProtectionPolicy("secret", "", ap);
```

This way the PDF can be opened with the empty password to be viewed. The user password is for opening with restricted rights, the owner password is to get all permissions (which you want to prevent).

Comment: When I try the suggestion; I still get the password screen and enter and the owner password won't open the document.

Comment: @user1623809 what version are you using? You should be using 1.8.9. Can you provide a link to the document before it is encrypted?

Comment: I am using 1.8.9. I am not encrypting the document. Is this a requirement?

Comment: protect() means that you encrypt it. Even if it is with an empty user password. That is the correct thing to do for what you want. It is a mystery to me that it doesn't work for you. Try also with the command line: https://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/commandline.html#encrypt

Comment: It seems that setting read only forces a password and then no password is acceptable.

Comment: If it still doesn't work, maybe try it on a non confidential PDF and upload that one before and after. You can also send it to me, tilman at snafu dot de. Attach the actual code you have been using. (But change the passwords)